# Facial Expression Transfer

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision

Given an input-image & an expression-image. I want to put the expression(smile,laugh,anger,etc) into input image. I have tried some logics using opencv & dlib. But couldnot generate any good result.

Method tried:

**A.** 1). Fetch landmark points of two faces. 2). Fetch the region of interest(whole face / lips / eyes /etc) 3). Use opencv shape transformation. Warp the ROI based of landmark-points-match 4). Put back the warped-ROI back into original image.

**B.** The ML project on git https://github.com/datitran/face2face-demo says to transfers expressions to only a specific person for which it is trained. But I want to have some generic.

Any guidance on what should be the correct/better path to take; Is there any known library ?

Comment: read about StarGAN